# Как прописать RewriteBase в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Привожу пример существующего кода:

```
 RewriteBase /demo/
```

Итак: как видим, папка `/demo/` относительно `url` запроса. То есть запрос делаем так `http://site.zone/demo/`. 
На сервере путь к папке такой `/path/demo/`. Соответственно, `http:://site.zone/` находится в папке `/path/`.

Задача: мы отдаем в хорошие, неумелые руки данный файл. Как нам прописать `RewriteBase` так, чтобы при смене имени папки `demo` ничего не ломалось и все продолжало работать без редактирования файла `htaccess`?

Comment: ИМХО - никак...

Comment: Думаем еще!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое мнение - никак.